# Conditions on recursive XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, recursive-regex

How can I use *recursive AND conditional* selection in XPath?

For example, given this document:

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
  <file name="foo.mp4">
    <chunks>
      <file>
        <chunks>
          <file>
          <chunks>
            <file>1</file>
            <file>2</file>
            <file>3</file>
            <file>4</file>
          </chunks>
          </file>
          <file>
          <chunks>
            <file>5</file>
            <file>6</file>
            <file>7</file>
            <file>8</file>
          </chunks>
          </file>
        </chunks>
      </file>
      <file>
        <chunks>
          <file>
          <chunks>
            <file>9</file>
            <file>10</file>
            <file>11</file>
            <file>12</file>
          </chunks>
          </file>
          <file>
          <chunks>
            <file>13</file>
            <file>14</file>
            <file>15</file>
            <file>16</file>
          </chunks>
          </file>
        </chunks>
      </file>
    </chunks>
  </file>
</root>
```

I would like to select just:

```
<file>1</file>
<file>2</file>
<file>3</file>
<file>4</file>
```

So, effectively this:

```
//[name="foo.mp4"]/chunks/*[1]/chunks/*[1]/*
```

But with a generalized approach -- i.e something that would cover even deeper-nested objects. Something like this:

```
//[name="foo.mp4"]/(chunks/*[1]/)+/*
```

`(cond)+` is not XPath syntax, and a regex-like representation of what I want.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a very poor requirements statement. You're effectively saying "if the input is 17 then I want the answer to be 23, but I want this generalised to work with any input". You need to give us the general rule for computing the output from the input; we can't infer it from one example.

Answer (score 5):

Recursion implies self-reference and is not directly available in XPath.  The usual way to ignore intervening levels of elements is via the `descendant-or-self` axis (`//`), anchored by a desired property.

**For example, each of the following XPath expressions,**

- *All `file` elements with values less than 5:*

  ```
  //file[number() < 5]
  ```
- *The first 4 leaf `file` elements:*

  ```
  //file[not(*)][count(preceding::file[not(*)]) < 4]
  ```
- *The `file` leaf elements whose ancestors have no predecessors:*

  ```
  //file[not(*)][not(ancestor::*[preceding::*])]
  ```

**will select**

```
<file>1</file>
<file>2</file>
<file>3</file>
<file>4</file>
```

**as requested.**

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as recursive XPath as far as I know. So you'll need to combine XPath with some other things like XSLT or a programming language to be able to do recursion. Using pure XPath, you'll need to formulate the requirement differently, if possible.

I don't know if this is applicable to your actual data, but if you can formulate the requirement to something like the following, for example :

> *"within `file[@name='foo.mp4']`, find the first `<chunk>` that contains **leaf** `<file>` i.e `<file>` element that doesn't contain any element, only text nodes, and return the **leaf** `<file>` elements"*

then there will be a possible pure XPath solution :

```
(//file[@name='foo.mp4']//chunks[not(file/*)])[1]/file
```

given sample XML in question, the expected output of `file` 1 to 4 are returned by the above XPath expression when tested [`here`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/577350f07a196c02847950252346fae9).